# radio streaming con php

Tags: php

Tengo un reproductor de musica funcionando, y necesito que los usuarios que se conecten escuchen musica en streaming, es decir al conectarse el usuario 1 comienza a sonar la cancion 1 de mi lista de canciones, cuando se conecte un segundo usuario necesito que la cancion que escuche ese segundo usuario sea la misma que esta escuchando el primero.

Es decir me conecto y estoy escuchando la cancion FERNANDO de abba, el segundo usuario se conecta 1 minuto despues de mi, ya la cancion habra reproducido 1 minuto, entonces ese segundo usuario debe de escuchar la misma cancion desde el minuto 1 en adelante,

este es el codigo que uso para traer las canciones desde la carpeta

```
<?php
//inicio lectura de canciones
$directoriomusica = __DIR__ . '/AUDIOS'; //ruta a la carpeta de canciones
$canciones = []; //creamos arreglo vacio
$directorioabierto = opendir($directoriomusica); //accedemos a la carpeta de canciones
while ($cancion = readdir($directorioabierto)) //obtenemos cancion por cancion
{
    if (!is_dir($cancion)) //verificamos que este correcto o exitas
    {
        array_push($canciones, $cancion); //agregamos la cancion al arreglo de canciones
    }
} //cerramos acceso a la carpeta de canciones
//fin lectura de canciones
// sort($canciones);//ordenar array (sort($canciones)=orden ascendente -- rsort($canciones)--orden descendente)
```

?>

Y este es el codigo con el cual coloco el reproductor en el navegador

```
<audio style="outline:none; max-width: 100%; display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0px;" preload id="Playing" controls controlsList="nodownload"></audio>
<br>
<center>
    <button id="butNext" onclick="Next()"  Next </button>
</center>
<center>
    <p id="nombre"></p>
</center>
```

en este momento al conectarse un usuario comienza a reproducirse la lista sin problemas, pero al conecarse otro usuario la lista comienza desde la 1 cancion y lo ideal es que si ya comenzo a reproducirse la lista los demas usuarios escuchen lo que esta en reproduccion, no que comience la lista.

Comment: Por favor da más detalles y publicá el código de lo que estás haciendo. Sino es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: Listo la pregunta fue editada